# I am looking to create a T--SQL procedure that will encompass the following

Tags: sql-server

I want to combine the use of `sp_MSforeachtable` with the `openquery` to get a list od tables and counts from a linked server:

ALL but the last command have worked so far

Get the count from a single table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(ACTIFIODB,'SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM public.applicationvw')

SELECT * FROM sys.servers
```

Get the count from all tables in a database:

```
CREATE TABLE #counts 
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'

SELECT * 
FROM #counts ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC
```

Need to combine the two into something like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM openquery(ACTIFIODB, 'EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'')
```

Comment: You want the row count of every single table from every single database? Be warned....this is not going to be fast no matter the solution. And be warned...sp_msforeachdb will sometimes miss databases.

Comment: So.. is the linked server also sql server?